# What is the best trading simulation platform for futures, swaps, options, etc.?

Tags: finance, trading, derivatives, hedging

I've just started studying derivatives from the "Options, futures, and other derivatives - J.C. Hull" and I'd like to see how to do hedging and trading transactions through a simulation platform or a demo account. What do you recommend me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the "best" but from personal experience:

Interactive Brokers: If you have a live account with IBr, they will give you a demo/paper trading account along side of it that you can use for testing purposes.  I used it a long time ago.  I don't remember if the simulated order fills were accurate but other than that it had the full functionality that a regular account would have including API access.

Lots of other brokers have demo/paper trading capabilities.  I wouldn't recommend using them for much other than testing very basic things like API functionality, order entry/cancellation, system messaging, etc.

Hope this helps.  It's not exactly on topic for this SE but I remember 25 years ago when I was looking for similar information as this and I am sympathetic.  Good luck.

Comment: The brokerage firm Thinkorswim (what a funny name) also offers a very nice paper trading account.